# Z Transform of M-Fold Decimation

Tags: z-transform, decimation, multirate

I know this is probably a common question, but after some searching I think that my version of the question is slightly different -- apologies if this is a repeat. I have seen that it is inaccurate to say the Z transform of the M-fold decimation process is

$$ Y(z) = X(z^{1/M}) $$

This incorrect version of decimation seems to be quite common actually, I have even seen it presented in graduate classes. I wonder why this expression is so common in classes and even practical literature despite it being wrong? If anyone has any insight on that, it'd be a great help if you could let me know!

Anyways, I've also seen that the correct expression for M-fold decimation is

$$Y_D(z) = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} X\left[z^{1/M} \exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi k}{M}\right)\right] $$

However, I'm wondering if the following approach to the M-fold decimator is also valid. Let's consider the fairly common special case of $M =2$. The Z transform of this sequence by definition is

$$ Y_D(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[2n] z^{-n}$$

and re-indexing gives the following sum (which I'm just going to call $F(z)$ for now since it's inaccurate to call this sum $Y_D(z)$):

$$F(z) = \sum_{2n} x[n]z^{-n/2} $$

Let's define the new sequence $x'[n]$ in the context of this $F(z)$ sum such that

$$x'[n] = \begin{cases}
x[n], & \text{if } n = 2k,\,\, k \in\mathbb{Z}\\
0, & \text{if } n = 2k+1, \,\, k \in\mathbb{Z}
\end{cases} $$

This sequence can easily be re-written as

$$x'[n] = \frac{x[n]}{2}\Big( 1 + (-1)^n\Big) $$

Then I'm basically going to claim that I can replace $x[n]$ in the $F(z)$ sum with this sequence to obtain

$$F(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x[n]}{2}\Big(1+(-1)^n\Big) z^{-n/2} $$

I figured this sum can be re-indexed over all integers due to the new sequence $x'[n]$. This sum can now be written in terms of the Z transform of $X$:

$$F(z) = \frac{X(\sqrt{z}) + X(-\sqrt{z})}{2} $$

The second term $X(-\sqrt{z})$ seems to indicate aliasing to me ($X(-z)$ indicates reflection in the magnitude response). This aliasing term is likely to be expected with decimation which makes me think I'm on the right path. I believe this $F(z)$ sum is exactly $Y_D(z)$ since if we now use the correct Z transform for M-fold decimation where $M=2$ we get

$$Y_D(z) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^1 X\left[z^{1/2} \exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi k}{2}\right)\right] =\frac{1}{2} \left( X\left[ z^{1/2} \exp(0) \right] + X\left[z^{1/2} \exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi }{2}\right)\right] \right)  $$

And after reducing the exponentials, the result reduces to $F(z)$:

$$Y_D(z) = \frac{X(z^{1/2}) + X(-z^{1/2})}{2} = F(z) $$

Therefore I feel like this whole $F(z)$ sum approach was correct, at least more correct than the common $X(z^{1/M})$ approach, but I feel like this was pretty hand-wavy and I'm wondering if I'm missing something that makes this approach completely invalid.

Any comments or corrections to this approach -- especially about the whole $x'[n]$ thing -- would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The $z$ transform is a tool for analyzing linear *shift invariant* systems, and decimation is inherently not shift-invariant.  So there is no universal "z transform of decimation" -- only various approximations, of various validity in various situations.